# Save (in an array) content of dynamic cells (from a tableView), at runtime

Tags: objective-c, nsarray, uitableview

How can I select (and save them in an array) the contents of the dynamic cells of my tableViewController?
My tableView is composed by 1 section always present, where I can set the number of sections to show at runtime.
The setting is controlled by a stepper. When I click the "+" button on stepper, a section with three rows is added to the table.
Each row consists of a textField! Considering that there may be even 1000 sections at runtime, how can I select the contents of those rows and save them in an array?
Here the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.arrDetails = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Name",@"Surname",@"Fix",@"Role", nil];}


- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1 + self.numberOfComponents;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{

    if (section == 0) {
        return 1;
    }


    else{
        return [self.arrDetails count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellStepper";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
        UILabel *stepperLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
        stepperLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",self.numberOfComponents];
        UIStepper *stepper = (UIStepper *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        stepper.minimumValue = 0;
        stepper.maximumValue = 20;
        stepper.stepValue = 1;
        //stepper.wraps = YES;
        stepper.autorepeat = YES;
        stepper.continuous = YES;
        return cell;
    }
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cellDetail";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UITextField *cellLabelComponent = (UITextField *)[cell viewWithTag:3];
    cellLabelComponent.placeholder = self.arrDetails[indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}


- (IBAction)stepperClik:(UIStepper *)stepper{
    if (stepper.value == 0 && self.numberOfComponents == 0) {
        if (stepper.value > self.numberOfComponents) {
            self.numberOfComponents += 1;
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
        }
        else{
            return;
        }
    }
    if (stepper.value > self.numberOfComponents) {
        self.numberOfComponents += 1;
        [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
    else{
        self.numberOfComponents -= 1;
        [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:1] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    }
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a fixed number of cells in a section and can access the number of sections with `self.numberOfComponents`, you can build an indexPath for each cell.

```
NSMutableArray *savedTexts = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (int i = 0; i < self.numberOfComponents; i < 0)
{
    NSMutableArray *component = [NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (int j = 0; j < [self.arrDetails count]; j < 0)
    {
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:j inSection:i+1];
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath];
        [component addObject: [cell viewWithTag:3].text];
    }
    [savedTexts addObject: component];
}
```

With this you should have an array of components, each of which contains its details.